# Replacing search results with custom external query

Tags: wp-query, search

I'd like to replace the existing search function with an external query (from Solr) but I'm having trouble showing the results in the `search.php` page. This is the code I have in `functions.php`:

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'my_search_query');

function my_search_query($query) {
    if($query->is_search() && $query->is_main_query() && get_query_var('s', false)) {   

    $desired_query = get_query_var('s', false);

    $url = 'http://{SOLR_SERVER}:8983/solr/{CORE}/select?indent=on&q=' . $desired_query . '~2&wt=json';
    $result = file_get_contents($url);
    $data = json_decode($result, true);

    $ids = array();
    foreach ($data['response']['docs'] as $item)
    {
        array_push($ids, $item['id']);
    }

    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    $query = new WP_Query(array(
        'post__in' => $ids,
        'post_type' => array('last-news','blog'), 
        'paged' => $paged, 
        'posts_per_page' => 5,
    ));

}
return $query;
}
```

And this is the `search.php`:

```
<section class="content">
    <div class="page-title pad group">
        <h1>
        <?php if ( have_posts() ): ?><i class="fa fa-search"></i><?php endif; ?>
        <?php if ( !have_posts() ): ?><i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle"></i><?php endif; ?>
        <?php echo $wp_query->found_posts  ?>
        <?php _e('Search Results','theme'); ?>
        </h1>
    </div>

    <div class="pad group">

        <div class="notebox">
            <?php _e('Found','theme'); ?> "<span><?php echo get_search_query(); ?></span>".
            <?php if ( !have_posts() ): ?>
                <?php _e('Try with another term:','theme'); ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <div class="search-again">
                <?php get_search_form(); ?>
            </div>
        </div>

        <?php 
            if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

            <div class="post-list group">
                <?php $i = 1;  while ( have_posts() ): the_post(); 
                echo '<div class="post-row">';
                 get_template_part('content'); echo '</div>'; endwhile;  ?>
            </div><!--/.post-list-->

            <?php get_template_part('inc/pagination'); ?>

        <?php endif; ?>

    </div><!--/.pad-->

</section><!--/.content-->
```

The echo `$wp_query->found_posts` returns the number '100' so it seems to be getting something but then the `have_posts()` functions returns a false value.

What am I doing wrong? I just want to return the posts in the `$ids` array whenever a search is done, I don't need no other filter.

**Edit (alternative solution):**

I also can do something like this:

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'my_search_query');
function my_search_query($query) {
    if($query->is_search() && $query->is_main_query() && get_query_var('s', false)) {   

    $desired_query = get_query_var('s', false);

    $url = 'http://{SOLR_SERVER}:8983/solr/{CORE}/select?indent=on&q=' . $desired_query . '~2&wt=json';
    $result = file_get_contents($url);
    $data = json_decode($result, true);

    $ids = array();
    foreach ($data['response']['docs'] as $item)
    {
        array_push($ids, $item['id']);
    }

    $query->set('post__in', $ids );
}
return $query;
}
```

The problem with this one is that the search, as I could understand, is going to be run with the search term and only will return the posts matching the term within the specific post ids. I don't want to make this operation, as I already did it with solr. Also, Solr allows me to make a Fuzzy query, but this won't work in this setting because the wordpress search will return 0 results, not finding the exact term.

Answer (score 2):

You can't return a query object from a `pre_get_posts` action. In fact, it shouldn't return anything, the query object is passed by reference.

Your second attempt is close, you can unset the `s` query var so WordPress doesn't try to search on that term. Of course, now `s` has no value, so any functions that try to output the search term will just get an empty string.

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'my_search_query');
function my_search_query($query) {
    if($query->is_search() && $query->is_main_query() && get_query_var('s', false)) {
        // get your $ids, then
        unset( $query->query_vars['s'] );
        $query->set( 'post__in', $ids );
    }
}
```

Comment: Unsetting query_vars outputs an error in the query and I end up getting no results.

Comment: The error probably tells you what the problem is, I can't guess what it might be though, I don't get an error with a default install and theme.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a little more on the answer here with some comments about what we're doing at each step, and how to convert it to work within WordPress' DB as well

```
#run before posts are grabbed from DB
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'my_search_query');
function my_search_query($query) {
    #global $wpdb; # used for internal with WP searching
    #is this query the main search query, and is there a search query provided?
    if($query->is_search() && $query->is_main_query() && get_query_var('s', false)) {

        #fun SQL goes here

            #INTERNAL
            #$sql = "" #SQL query
            #$results = $wpdb->get_results( $sql ); # used for internal with WP searching

            #EXTERNAL
            #$url = 'http://yourapi.com/json'; #go out to an api or something
            #$result = file_get_contents($url);
            #$results = json_decode($result, true);

        #create array to hold returned ids
        $ids = array();
        #loop through each and grab ID
        foreach ($results as $item) {
            array_push($results, $item['id']);
        }
        #make sure there are posts if you're going to replace search
        if( ! empty( $ids )) { 
            #Tell original WP search to shove it
            unset( $query->query_vars['s'] );
            #replace the current query with your results
            $query->set( 'post__in', $ids );

        }

    }
    #send back the query whether we touched it, or it didn't match our parameters
    return $query;
}
```